# Determine the time packets entered the network buffers

Tags: .net, sockets, udp, udpclient

I made a change to an existing program that uses `UdpClient` to receive multicast UDP packets.

The UDP packets are sent via `tcpreplay-edit --pps=...`  during these test.

To make a before/after (original version vs. one with my changes) comparison of the time the program needs to process incoming packets, I take the difference of a `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` taken in the receive thread directly after `UdpClient.Receive()`ing, and again at a later point when the packet has been processed (in a different thread).

Problem is, if the receive thread in the changed version is faster than it was before, say because it just hands off the received packet as fast as possible in order to return receiving the next packet, whereas the original version does other things inbetween receiving individual packets, the *after* processing time will in fact look worse.

Is there a way to determine the **timestamp when the packet was added to the network buffer without changing the overall way the receive threads work**?

Or do I have to add another thread that only receive packets, adds a timestamp, and puts it into a queue for consumption by the thread that currently receives the packets (besides other work it does)?

(Let's assume my receive buffer is always big enough, or my receive threads are always fast enough so that the buffer will not fill up, which would obviously affect the times measured)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'll do:

- Remember the timestamp of the first UDP packet ever to arrive: `incomingTimestamp[0]`
- Log `timestampAfterProcessing[packetNo] - incomingTimestamp[0]`

(In contrast, my original attempt as stated in the question was `timestampAfterProcessing[packetNo] - incomingTimestamp[packetNo]`)

The logged numbers should be independent of whatever delays there are in the respective receive threads, and hence could be used for before/after comparison. This is

- assuming that `tcpreplay-edit` replays the packets with more or less the same timing every time (will double-check at least the total time `tcpreplay-edit` takes each time)
- making sure my socket receive buffers don't overflow, otherwise comparison gets harder